# Need Help Drawing an Image in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, timer, paintcomponent

what I am trying to do is Have one image display on the screen for x amount of seconds and then disappear then have another one drawn in its place, I have got the first Image to display but the second one doesn't work. **Note: I can draw shapes but not the Image**

```
package com.mainwindow.draw;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainWindow extends JPanel {

Image Logo;
Image Menu;
String LogoSource = "Gimijes.png";
String menuEntity = "Menu.png";
Boolean draw = true; 

static Boolean timeout = false;

public MainWindow() {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(LogoSource));
    Logo = ii.getImage();
    ImageIcon mii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(menuEntity));
    Menu = mii.getImage();
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            draw = false;
            timeout = true;
            repaint();

        }
    });

    timer.start();
};

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (draw == true) {
        //draw Gimijes.png (on screen for 5 seconds)
        g2.drawImage(Logo, 0, 0, null);             
    }
    if (timeout  == true) {
        g2.drawImage(Menu, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

    }       
    }   
}
```

If anyone knows how to get this to work I would be really gratefull.

Comment: Is this `JPanel` being added to a JFrame?

Comment: getWidth(), getHeight() returns proper value from getPreferredSize for JPanel, search for here

Comment: You might have a threading issue here, the Timer thread may change timeout to true, but it looks like the EDT (which is executing paintComponent) is never told to take a new look at your timeout variable.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove The Swing Timer executes actionPerfoemed with the context of the EDT, repaint requests that the component be repainted, which places a repaint event into the Event Queue which will (eventually) call paintComponent. By its very nature, the two events occur one after the other, it's impossible. For it to occur in any other order...

Comment: I suspect you have an image loading issue. Try using ImageIO.read instead of ImageIcon, as this will throw an IOException when something goes wrong

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah that's right, thought he was using a java.util.Timer, although there was more than one hint that he was not... :o

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the position of new image. If you want to override existing image then use same coordinate (position [0,0]).

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (draw == true) {
        // draw Gimijes.png (on screen for 5 seconds)
        g2.drawImage(Logo, 0, 0, null);
    }
    if (timeout == true) {
        g2.drawImage(Menu, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: `g2.drawImage(.., 0, 0, null);` should best be `g2.drawImage(.., 0, 0, this);` since every `Component` **is an** `ImageObserver`.